# SMS to multiple numbers not working in my app

Tags: android

I have been trying to get multiple SMSs through the following code.

```
private void sendSMS() {
    try {
        phoneNumber = phoneEditText.getText().toString();
        donorName = donorNameEditText.getText().toString();
        message = String.format(message, donorName, phoneNumber, donationAmount);

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        //ArrayList<String> smsParts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(defaultPhoneNumber1, null, message, null, null);
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(defaultPhoneNumber2, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.record_donation_constraint_layout), invalidDestinationAddress, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Have checked similar messages and tried those methods in-vain. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: have you given SEND_SMS permission to the app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977424/3983054

Comment: for SMS Manager SEND_SMS permission is mandatory

Comment: Yes. The first one goes OK

Comment: Only the first message is working ? Can you check my answer

Comment: defaultPhoneNumber1  & defaultPhoneNumber2 from where your getting ?

Comment: They are static, not taken from User Input.

Comment: Why my question is set to -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by introducing a delay of 9 sec and 7 seconds between each of my posted code. Tested several times with several delays and found the optimal values with 5 different devices and versions of Android.

```
try{
            Thread.sleep(9000);
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to request the send SMS permission in your AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Then you can do something along these lines.

```
  // you need to import the Sms Manager
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;

    // fetch the Sms Manager
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();


        phoneNumber = phoneEditText.getText().toString();
        defaultPhoneNumber1 = defaultPhoneNumber1.getText().toString();
        defaultPhoneNumber2 = defaultPhoneNumber2.getText().toString();
        donorName = donorNameEditText.getText().toString();
        message = String.format(message, donorName, phoneNumber, donationAmount);

    // the phone numbers we want to send to
    String numbers[] = {phoneNumber , defaultPhoneNumber1 ,defaultPhoneNumber2 };

    for(String number : numbers) {
      sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: added the permission. First one goes OK

Comment: Check the solution as well.

Comment: Did not work. Even introduced a delay of 1000ms. The first one goes through and that's it.